# How can we extract complete retweet network of a tweet

Tags: python, api, twitter, graph, sna

I want to make complete retweet network of a tweet. for example, user A tweet which was retweeted by 2 of his followers B and C. D and E which were followers of B retweeted the same tweet retweeted by B.
when I write python code using twitter API it returns that A's Tweet retweeted by B, C, D, E...
I am interested to get the actual network.

```
user = "k"
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream


ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''


twitter = Twitter ( auth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, 
CONSUMER_SECRET)) 

results = twitter.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name = user)

for status in results:
     print ("@%s %s" % (user, status["text"]))

    retweets = twitter.statuses.retweets._id(_id = status["id"])
     for retweet in retweets:
         print (" - retweeted by %s" % (retweet["user"]["screen_name"]))
```

Please guide me or send correct link
Thanks